# Django Custom Commands: Will writing to SQLite DB with a custom command while the server is running fail due to File Lock?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, locking

I would like to keep the django server running as I call some custom commands that will read / write to the sqlite DB. However I'm nervous that this may conflict due to the main server locking the database file.

Is this cause for concern ?

I can't use PostgreSQL or MySQL.

I tried this and it didn't throw any errors, however I would like to know if this is something that **can** occur.